# How to install latex in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, latex

Please help me install latex (texstudio or texlive or any other package) in my laptop. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 7):

To install TeX Live in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

The TeX Live software distribution offers a complete TeX system. It encompasses programs for typesetting, previewing and printing of TeX documents in many different languages, and a large collection of TeX macros and font libraries. The texlive metapackage provides a decent selection of the TeX Live packages which should suffice for the most common tasks.

To install TeXstudio in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install texstudio
```

TeXstudio is a program based on Texmaker, which integrates many tools needed to develop documents with LaTeX in just one application. Using its editor you can write your documents with the help of interactive spell checking, syntax highlighting, code completion and more.

Comment: Hi karel, it gave error in building dependency tree. Error message is: the following packages have unmet dependencies.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get install texlive`